# -su: ./start-all.sh: No such file or directory in Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

-su: ./start-all.sh: No such file or directory
getting this error while ruining /start-all.sh command  in Ubuntu.

Comment: could you add some more details please? (e.g., which path you run this command from, hadoop version, ...) stuff like that are necessary for us to know what your problem is.

Comment: i am using this command in  cd /usr/local/hadoop

Answer (score 1):

Go to parent dir (the path in which hadoop is installed, typically stored as `$HADOOP_HOME`) and run:

```
./bin/start-all.sh
```

With this much info you provide, that's all I can suggest.

Comment: user@KELLGGNCPU0123:/usr/local$ ls
bin  etc  games  hadoop  hadoop-2.7.1  include  lib  man  netbeans-8.0.2  sbin  share  src
user@KELLGGNCPU0123:/usr/local$ $HADOOP_HOME
user@KELLGGNCPU0123:/usr/local$ ./bin/start-all.sh
bash: ./bin/start-all.sh: No such file or directory
user@KELLGGNCPU0123:/usr/local$ 
Its not working for me

Comment: what about `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/` ?

Comment: well, try to find where you have downloaded hadoop, using ls, or go back to the tutorial you have followed in case you remember where you stored it. It may be under hadoop-2.7.1. Look for the path of start-all.sh and go back to its parent dir (the parent of bin/)